# trouble/busy/at home/... doing something

Tags: phrases, present-participles

I have a grammar question about the role of these bold "doing" in the below sentences and why they have "ing" form?

> I am busy **doing** my homework.

> I have trouble **doing** my homework.

> I am at home **doing** my homework.

Comment: ***doing my homework*** (and single-word verb forms such as *I'm busy **working**, I have trouble **breathing**, I'm at home **reading***) look to me like "adverbial elements of purpose / outcome". But apart from the matter of what to ***call*** them, what exactly is it you don't understand about such usages?

Comment: Thanks. I want to know the grammar role of these structures(to review in grammar books), and accordingly use similar examples in my writings.

Comment: In all your examples, the adverbial element starting with the word ***doing*** could in principle be discarded. What's left would still be a valid statement - just lacking in some *detail* (exactly *what* are you busy / having trouble with / doing at home?).

Comment: could you refer me to a link or whatsoever describing it in detail? if doing is discarded, the remaining sentence does not make sense for me. I am busy "my homework"? unless we say: I am busy with my homework.

Comment: I said you could discard the *entire* adverbial phrase starting with the word "doing"in each case. There's nothing "unusual" about the sentences *I am busy* and *I am at home*. You wouldn't be so likely to just say *I have trouble*, but syntactically it's not *necessary* for even that one to be followed by an adverbial clause (defining *what* I'm having trouble doing).